# Search return wrong result with special character like @#! in Craft 3

Tags: craft3

I have implemented search in Craft 3, but it returns wrong result when I enter some special characters like @#!. Is there a way to prevent it?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more specifics, Craft will "normalize" search keywords before putting them into the search index table in the database, and one of the steps in the normalization process is to remove punctuation, which is why searching for punctuation doesn't work.

You can see the whole normalization process here: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/src/helpers/Search.php#L41-L81